# Monitor resolution messed up somehow

Tags: windows-7, display, refresh-rate

I purchased the Westinghouse 22" LCD LCM-22w3 a few years ago, and now it's been acting up on me. I just booted into Windows 7(without changing any settings), and the default resolution is 1600x1024, and it allows me to select a refresh rate of up to 85 Hz(it didn't let me do that). I usually have my resolution set to 1680x1050 with a refresh rate of 60 Hz. Now, that resolution does not even appear in the list. Does anyone have any idea of what could be the problem and how to fix it?

Edit: I am not sure if this will help, but when I go to change the screen resolution, the monitor is known as "Generic Non-PnP Monitor". It used to be referred to as "Generic PnP Monitor). I tried to disable Generic Non-PnP Monitor, but when I restart, it uses that monitor again.

Edit 2: I created a custom .inf file using Powerstrip, but that does not work either. The monitor settings are being stubborn.

Answer (score 1):

Look into updating your drivers for your Video Card. Once that is done see if there is a separate video settings options for your video card listed in the control panel.

Usually when certain manufacturers install their own settings panels they override the video settings with the OS. Try messing with the resolutions listed in that control panel option

Comment: Hello, I am updated to the latest drivers for my video card, I even reinstalled them to make sure. I am only able to change to standard screen resolutions(1600x1024) for some reason. When I go to my monitor settings, it says that I am at 1680x1050.

Answer (score 1):

What happened to my laptop was that its resolution was set to 1024x768 and my normal resolution was 1366x768.

If you click on multiple displays, and then go on "show desktop only on 1" and click apply, it should fix. At least it did on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgraded your graphic drivers?

Anyway you can begin by getting your screen driver from the manufacturer website and update your graph card drivers as well.
I guess an auto-update messed up with the drivers.

Comment: Hello, I did not upgrade my graphic drivers. I will try to update the, though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem: part of my basic troubleshooting action list :P

Comment: Hello, it didn't seem to work. It just happened out of nowhere. I think it may be a monitor problem. When I go to my monitor settings, it says that it is displaying at 1680x1050.

Answer (score 0):

If windows knows about (or thinks it knows about) your monitor then the list of possible resolutions you are offered may be restricted to those that windows thinks that your monitor can cope with. On windows XP (I guess Win7 will have something similar), you can go to "display properties" Then click "advanced" Then click the "adaptor" tab. The click "list all modes". This will give you a complete list of all the display modes that your graphics card can output regardless of whatever monitor windows thinks you have. Now you can select the one that suits your monitor best.

Alternatively - you may want to use device manager to check out what monitor windows 7 thinks you have. If it has the wrong idea then go through the "add new hardware" process to fix it.

Comment: Hello, when I select list all modes, the resolution only goes up to 1600 x 1024, which is what my monitor is set to now. It is only listing standard screen sizes (up to 1600 x 1024) and standard screen refresh rates (up to 60 Hz).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with this Monitor LCM-22W3 but on Windows 10, My problem; was I updated drivers and got locked into 640x480 resolution. My solution; was to go and run "msconfig" I setup a safe mode reboot. Once I am in safe mode I just lock the resolution to 1680x1050 60hz, then return to "msconfig" disable safe mode. Restart Windows 10 normally and running at the resolution recommended by manufacturer.

Specs
AMD Ryzen 1700; AMD R7 370; Windows 10 OS build 16299.125